# Getting error while executing query

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
String req="INSERT INTO`fos_user`(`addressmailperso`,`pays`,`job`,`sexe`, `addressjob`,`skills`,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE username='"+Apptest.current+"';";
```

this error occured: Syntax error near 'WHERE username ='fayrouz''in line 1.

Comment: using binding instead of quoating

Comment: There is no `WHERE` in a standard `INSERT` statement. You probably need an `UPDATE` statement instead.

Comment: Either use update or do not use where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In insert there is not where  so you should use

String req="INSERT 
         INTO `fos_user` (`addressmailperso`,`pays`,`job`,`sexe`, `addressjob`,`skills`,`description`) 
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

could be you need  an update

```
  String req="UPDATE `fos_user`
        set `addressmailperso` = ? 
        ,`pays`  = ? 
        ,`job` =? 
        ,`sexe` = ? 
        , `addressjob` =?
        ,`skills` = ? 
        ,`description` =? 
  WHERE username='"+Apptest.current+"';";
```

Comment: I changed the query to : " UPDATE fos_user SET addressmailperso = ? , pays = ? ,job = ?, sexe = ?, addressjob = ?, skills = ? , description = ? WHERE username = " +Apptest.current; But I still have an error: Field 'fayrouz' unknown in where clause. Btw, Apptest.current is a variable that contains the username of the current user of the application wich is Fayrouz.

Comment: @FayrouzOuerghi        you must wrap the  Apptest.current  with single  quotes like in my sample code.    in your code  (the code you provided in comment)       you missed  the single quote. If you don't use quote around the var  the name is assumed  as column name and not as a literal value .. so look how the single quotes are placed  in req string